# Android Studio app shows only a white background and title

Tags: java, android

After installing the APK on mobile phone (a Samsung), I'm opening it and all i see is a white background and the title. It is basically a simple browser.
When I open the app on the mobile phone it opens the phone's keyboard, it is like the elements are there but are covered by a white background.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Introdu aici site-ul.."
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="22dp"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Accesează"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8">

</LinearLayout>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="415dp"
    android:layout_height="548dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-4dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="62dp"></WebView>
```

AND BUILD GRADLE:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dambrowser"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Please add your apps build.gradle file. I think, you might need to test a different Version of the Build Tools. I had the same behaviour with 2 versions of the buid tools

Comment: Done.. I have added it.

Comment: Can you update your question with your full layout code?

Comment: Please try 28.0.3 as Version for your build Tools and recompile

Comment: In my case this was due to the missing size information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57960814/785529